# Term or Phrase for evidence converging or overlapping on one possibility?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a term or phrase that will be widely understood to refer to a range of evidence and possibilities when all put together pointing to one or a few specific options.

Imagine twenty Venn Diagrams overlapping on one tiny spot.

The term or phrase does not have to be simplistic, it can be technical as it would be used in a possibly more academic or serious setting. At the same time, it's meaning should immediately be understood by a diverse audience, self explanatory even.

**Usage example**:

> "The Detective thought through every possibility; through every piece of evidence they had gathered. As he put the pieces together, he began to see **[insert your answer]** pointed to only one scenario that fit."

To clarify, I not looking for simply "complete the sentence". Also, I am not looking for just a preponderance or consensus of evidence, but rather something that conveys the idea of a complexity of possibilities that don't necessarily agree except on one point or only fit together in one way.

Comment: ... he began to see ***that it all*** pointed to only one scenario that fit.

Comment: @Jim The example is so simple because I cut out other words so as to allow answers some grammatical flexibility. For example, "to see the confluence of evidence pointed". The point was not to simplify the phrase. "That it all" in no way communicates everything I'm asking independently. It cannot stand on its own.

Comment: As he put the pieces together, (he began to see) [the evidence in aggregate] point[ing]ed to only one scenario that fit.

Comment: @PhilSweet so that would be the more technical way of putting it? The optional or explanatory parts could go in parentheses leaving the brackets for the answer? Thanks! I'm new here.

Comment: It is a bit forced to fit your template, but some sense of aggregate would work. I'm pretty new here too, so still getting the hang of it. Braces are preferred when fiddling with some one else's quote.

Comment: @PhilSweet You or any answer can feel free to make your own example sentence that best exemplifies your answer. I'm not tied to my example, it's probably not even a good one. I'm not asking for it with a certain instance in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Consider: [a confluence of evidence](https://briankoberlein.com/2014/09/17/confluence/)

> **confluence**
>
> con·flu·ence
>
> ˈkänˌflo͞oəns/Submit
>
> noun
>
> 1. the junction of two rivers, especially rivers of approximately equal width.
>
> "here at the confluence of the Laramie and North Platte Rivers"
>
> synonyms:  convergence, meeting, junction
>
> "the confluence of the Rhine and the Mosel"
>
> **2. an act or process of merging.**
>
> "a major confluence of the world's financial markets"
>
> [google: confluence](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=confluence%20definition)

Answer (score 2):

Even if the expression has a legal flavour, "**corroborating presumptions**" would also fit in a scientific context.

> *Corroborate* definition: To strengthen, confirm or support with other
>   evidence; make more certain.
>
> *Presumption* definition:  A condition, basis or inference for accepting
>   or assuming something.

Answer (score 1):

### [Consilience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consilience)

> In science and history, consilience (also convergence of evidence or concordance of evidence) refers to the principle that evidence from independent, unrelated sources can "converge" to strong conclusions. That is, when multiple sources of evidence are in agreement, the conclusion can be very strong even when none of the individual sources of evidence is significantly so on its own.

---

Your usage sentence seems so simple and I think the first comment itself fits the bill.

As @Jim said

> ... he began to see ***that it all*** pointed to only one scenario that fit.

This simply works and is understood by most, if not all.

[**point to something**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/point+to)

> to indicate, reveal, or suggest something.
>
> *"All the evidence seems to point to his guilt."*
>
> *"The signs point to a very cold winter."*

Also try,

[**Converge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consilience)

> To tend toward or achieve union or a common conclusion or result
>
> *"In time, our views and our efforts converged."*

Answer (score 1):

You can call it *the common thread*, particularly if it links several clues or ideas.

> **Common thread**
>   A theme or characteristic found in various stories or situations: *a common thread through most of the stories is the support from the family*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/common-thread?q=common%20thread)

Your sample sentence would then be:

- The Detective thought through every possibility; through every piece of evidence they had gathered. As he put the pieces together, he began to see *that the common thread* pointed to only one scenario that fit.